# Active Object Pattern in Concurrent Java 1.5+

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrent-programming, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to develop [active object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) in concurrent Java using `java.util.concurrent` classes.

I describe it using a `Client` and a `Server`. A sample `Server` is as:

```
class Server implements Runnable {
  public final LinkedBlockingQueue que = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
  private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  private Message currentMessage;

  private boolean state = false;

  public init() {
    es.submit(this);
  }

  public void requestForServer() {
    if (state) {
      this.currentMessage.await();
    }
    state = true;
  }

  public void run() {
     for(;;) {
       Message m = que.take();
       this.currentMessage = m;
       this.es.submit(m);           
     }
  }

}
```

And a sample `Client`:

```
class Client {

  private Server server;

  public Client(Server s) {
    this.server = s;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    Message m = new Message(new Callable() {
      public Object call() {
        server.requestForServer();
      }
    });
    this.server.que.add(m);
  }

}
```

And a sample `Message` encapsulation is:

```
class Message<V> extends FutureTask<V> {
  private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private Condition condition = new Condition();

  public Message(Callable<V> callable) {
    super(callable);
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      lock.lock();
      super.run();
      lock.unlock();
    } catch(Exception e) {}
  }

  public void await() {
    try {
      condition.await();
    } catch(Exception e) {}
  }

  public void signal() {
    try {
      condition.signalAll();
    } catch(Exception e) {}
  }

}
```

And a sample running code:

```
Server s = new Server();
Client c = new Client (s);
s.init();
c.doSomething();
```

**I dropped some implementation details to get my message across.**

Now, the problem is when in `Server` the `state` is `true` so the incoming message should wait and the `await` is called on the current message. However, I get `IllegalMonitorStateException` which means that the current message does not own the current thread to await on it. But, I believe this is strange since the current message gets called in the `Server` and its thread pool so the current message has also an access to the current thread of execution.

I'd be most thankful for any ideas or suggestions, or with a known working implementation of this pattern using `java.util.concurrent`. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:
I discussed the solution I could deploy in this [blog post](http://narmnevis.com/1389/12/implementing-active-object-pattern-with-concurrent-java-1/). I hope it could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually acquire the lock when you await on its corresponding condition.  Without that lock you cannot associate yourself to the condition directly.  To demonstrate this:

```
  public void await() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      condition.await();
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    finally{
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
```

That should resolve your IllegalMonitorStateException

On a side note of correctness you should always release a lock in a try{ } finally{ } manner, you can observe what I wrote as an example.  The reason for this is if an exception occurs between `lock().lock();` and `super.run();` `lock.unlock()` will never be called.

Comment: @john-v Thanks for the reply. However, this does not fix the problem and I think it makes sense not to since this idea is just replacing the location of locking.

Comment: @Berooz are you still getting the IllegalMonitorStateException or are you getting some other exception?